# Where are my wallets created with cleos wallet create + eosio in docker?

Tags: cleos, wallet, docker, keys

Following [learn-about-wallets-keys-and-accounts](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/learn-about-wallets-keys-and-accounts-with-cleos) tutorial in eos website I created my default wallet running:

`cleos wallet create`

And according to the tutorial my wallet should be in `~/eosio-wallet`, see:

```
The file for this wallet is named default.wallet. 
By default, keosd stores wallets in the ~/eosio-wallet folder.
```

However, the folder does not exist.

I also ran `sudo locate wallet / | grep --color default.wallet` but could not find the files.

I am sure the wallet is being created because eosio returns an error if I try to create the same wallet twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the  [Docker Quickstart](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart) tutorial. 
In short, the files are inside the Docker Container running the eosio instance.

To find the files inside the docker do the following:

1. Find the path to the wallet:

There might be better ways to do that, but the way I did was reading eosio logs  running in one terminal `docker logs --tail 10 eosio -f` while I try to recreate the same wallet in a SECOND terminal using `cleos wallet create`. If it is the second time I ran this command I will see the following error in the terminal two `Error 3120001: Wallet already exists`
While in the terminal one, running eosio logs, I can see the followng:

`Wallet with name: 'default' already exists at /mnt/dev/data/./default.wallet`

Keep this path in mind for now.

2. Find the container ID running `docker ps`.
   In my case, the output was:

   CONTAINER ID -------- IMAGE ----------------- [...Othe Columns ...]

   05e5bb8f0091 ---------- eosio/eos-dev -------- [...Other entries..]

My container ID was `05e5bb8f0091`

3. Bash inside the container, find the file in the path from step 1.

To bash inside the container run the following:

sudo docker exec -it 05e5bb8f0091 /bin/bash

Done, find the wallets in the path from step 1.:

`ls mnt/dev/data/`

Comment: You can combine step 2&3 using, 
docker exec -it $(docker ps -aqf "name=eosio") bash